# Linq Select Data based on a value in another table

Tags: c#, linq

I have the linq statements listed below and I want to restrict the records from one table based on the value in another table. This is the code I have which works:

```
using (context = new DocEntityConnection())
{
   var Docs = context.tbDocsDetails.Where(md => md.IsCurrentDetails && md.tbDoc.StatusID == 9).ToList(); 
   this.approves = context.tbDocApproves.ToList().Where(a => Docs.Select(x => x.DocID).ToList().Contains(a.DocID)).ToList();
   return Docs.Select(md => GetDataItem(md)).ToList();
}
```

There is another table called `tbDocStatus` which has a `DocId` field too
I would like to only return records from `tbDocDetails` where `tbDocdetails.DocId = tbDocStatus.DocId` and `tbDocStatus.StatusId = 4`.

How would I add that to my code shown above?

Answer (score 0):

That you need is a `join`

```
var Docs = from docDetail in context.tbDocsDetails
           join docStatus in context.tbDocStatus
           on docDetail.DocId = docStatus.DocId
           where docStatus.StatusId == 4 
           select docDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (context = new DocEntityConnection())
{
var Docs = context.tbDocsDetails.Where(md => md.IsCurrentDetails && md.tbDoc.StatusID ==  9).ToList(); 

var DocsFiltered = from d in Docs
               join docStatus in context.tbDocStatus
               on d.DocId equals docStatus.DocId
               where docStatus.StatusId = 4
               select d

this.approves = context.tbDocApproves.ToList().Where(a => Docs.Select(x =>       x.DocID).ToList().Contains(a.DocID)).ToList();
return DocsFiltered.Select(md => GetDataItem(md)).ToList();
}
```